# How to generate output of var_label()?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to get the label output in shiny using `textOutput` function with `var_label` from the `labelled` package. I tried a couple of things but I'm not able to view the label in the output. The error I'm getting is `Error in var_label.data.frame: object 'var1' not found`.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(labelled)
library(haven)

dat <- read_spss("http://staff.bath.ac.uk/pssiw/stats2/SAQ.sav")


ui <- fluidPage(
     sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("var1", "Frequency Table", choices =  names(dat), selected = NULL)
        ),

        mainPanel(
            verbatimTextOutput("name"),
           textOutput("label")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$name <- renderPrint({
        input$var1
    })
    
    output$label <- renderText({
        var_label(input$var1)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `input$var1` is the name of the variable. It does not contain any information about the variable in your dataset. To get the label associated with the variable called `input$var1` use `var_label(dat[[input$var1]])`.